# JavaScript - Making canvas a global variable

Tags: javascript, html

Right now, I am messing around HTML5 and using JavaScript to make a simple 2D Tile map. It's going well however I realized I cannot put everything inside one giant function.

I'm trying to make `canvas` and `context` variable global as in accessable by other functions. Right now, it's only available on "on load"... how do I make it in its own? When I put the `canvas` and `context` create variables... I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getContext' of null`

Here is my SSCCE:

```
// HTML5 JS Tile Example

// Set return 2D array of map
function loadMap(map) {
    if (map == 1) {
        return [
        [67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 190, 190, 67, 1, 1, 1, 1], [67, 393, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 190, 190, 448, 1, 166, 166, 1], [67, 343, 343, 393, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 448, 1, 166, 166, 1], [67, 1, 1, 1, 439, 1, 1, 1, 343, 13, 13, 13, 43, 166, 166, 1], [67, 1, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 1, 343, 13, 343, 448, 1, 166, 166, 1], [67, 1, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 1, 343, 13, 343, 448, 1, 166, 166, 1], [67, 1, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 1, 343, 13, 343, 448, 1, 319, 1, 1], [67, 1, 25, 1, 166, 321, 25, 1, 343, 13, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 67], [67, 424, 424, 424, 13, 424, 424, 424, 343, 13, 343, 343, 343, 394, 343, 67], [370, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 67, 67, 343, 343, 343, 67], [67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 370, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67]];
    }
}

// On load...
window.onload = function () {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var imageObj = new Image();
    var tiles = [];
    var board = loadMap(1);

    canvas.width = 512;
    canvas.height = 352;

    // 2. SET UP THE MAP TILES
    for (x = 0; x <= 520; x++) {
        imageObj = new Image(); // new instance for each image
        imageObj.src = "line_tile/t" + x + ".png";
        tiles.push(imageObj);
    }
    var theX;
    var theY;
    // 3. DRAW MAP BY ROWS AND COLS
    for (x = 0; x <= 10; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y <= 15; y++) {

            theX = x * 32;
            theY = y * 32;
            context.drawImage(tiles[board[x][y]], theY, theX, 32, 32);
        }
    }
};
```

Online example: http://mystikrpg.com/html5/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just remove the `var` declarations and declare the variables outside:

```
// HTML5 JS Tile Example

// Set return 2D array of map
function loadMap(map) {
    if (map == 1) {
        return [
        [67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 190, 190, 67, 1, 1, 1, 1], [67, 393, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 190, 190, 448, 1, 166, 166, 1], [67, 343, 343, 393, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 448, 1, 166, 166, 1], [67, 1, 1, 1, 439, 1, 1, 1, 343, 13, 13, 13, 43, 166, 166, 1], [67, 1, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 1, 343, 13, 343, 448, 1, 166, 166, 1], [67, 1, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 1, 343, 13, 343, 448, 1, 166, 166, 1], [67, 1, 166, 166, 166, 166, 166, 1, 343, 13, 343, 448, 1, 319, 1, 1], [67, 1, 25, 1, 166, 321, 25, 1, 343, 13, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 67], [67, 424, 424, 424, 13, 424, 424, 424, 343, 13, 343, 343, 343, 394, 343, 67], [370, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 67, 67, 343, 343, 343, 67], [67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 370, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67]];
    }
}

// On load...

var canvas;
var context;

window.onload = function () {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var imageObj = new Image();
    var tiles = [];
    var board = loadMap(1);

    canvas.width = 512;
    canvas.height = 352;

    // 2. SET UP THE MAP TILES
    for (x = 0; x <= 520; x++) {
        imageObj = new Image(); // new instance for each image
        imageObj.src = "line_tile/t" + x + ".png";
        tiles.push(imageObj);
    }
    var theX;
    var theY;
    // 3. DRAW MAP BY ROWS AND COLS
    for (x = 0; x <= 10; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y <= 15; y++) {

            theX = x * 32;
            theY = y * 32;
            context.drawImage(tiles[board[x][y]], theY, theX, 32, 32);
        }
    }
};
```

This will create the variables in global scope.

Comment: You know what? I must not be getting sleep because I knew this but then again I just needed to be reminded... thanks bardiir.